# Como decodificiar um JSON Array no Android

Tags: java, android, json, array

Surgiu a necessidade de decodificar um `JSON Array` assim:

output: `[ [{ }, { }], [{ }, { }] ]`

Estava fazendo de uma maneira que decodificava um `Array` desse jeito:

output: `[{ }, { }, { }]`

Código de como estava fazendo:

<sub>**Método pra converter em Entidade**</sub>

```
private CardapioEntities convertCardapio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
    String titulo = obj.getString(TAG_TITULO);
    String descricao = obj.getString(TAG_DESCRICAO);
    String preco = obj.getString(TAG_PRECO);
    String tipo = obj.getString(TAG_TIPO);

    return new CardapioEntities(titulo, descricao, preco, tipo);
}
```

<sub>**Método para adicionar a ListView**</sub>

```
private void _getCardapio(String result) {
    //...
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                //...
                cardapioEntities.setCardapioPreco(convertCardapio(json.getJSONObject(i)).getCardapioPreco());
                listaLanches.add(cardapioEntities);
        }
        //...
        final ListView lvLanches = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLanches);
        lvLanches.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listaLanches));
        //...
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## Pergunta:

Como adaptar esse código para ler o `Json Array`? Exemplifique.

## EDIÇÃO:

Conforme a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31949/4591) do [@Wakim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6436/wakim), surgiu outra duvida:
Por que o objeto está repetindo na `ListView`? Acho que é erro de Lógica rs.

```
private void _getCardapio(String result) {
    //...
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            CardapioEntities cardapioEntities = new CardapioEntities();
            JSONArray arrayDentroDoArray = json.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayDentroDoArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject objeto = arrayDentroDoArray.getJSONObject(j);

                if (convertCardapio(objeto).getCardapioTipo() == 0) {
                    cardapioEntities.setCardapioTitulo(convertCardapio(objeto).getCardapioTitulo());
                    cardapioEntities.setCardapioDescricao(convertCardapio(objeto).getCardapioDescricao());
                    cardapioEntities.setCardapioPreco(convertCardapio(objeto).getCardapioPreco());
                    listaLanches.add(cardapioEntities);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: Imagem ilustrativa]

Comment: Basta usar o método `getJSONArray(int index)`, ele vai retornar o que você quer.

Comment: @Wakim Pode mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: O erro é onde está instanciando o `CardapioEntities`, crie a instância dentro da iteração mais interna. Pois ele está sempre modificando a mesma instância dentro da iteração, e a última alteração é que prevalece.

Comment: @Wakim, puts! É vdd, até me esqueci dele kk; Tudo certo agora, obrigado (:

Comment: Por que você nao usa a lib [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) para fazer isso ?, com a lib vc vai deixar a cargo do GSON fazer todo o trabalho seu codigo vai ficar muito mais simples, limpo e mais protegido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para buscar um `Array` dentro de um `JSONArray` é através do método [`getJSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONArray(int)).

Usando seu método:

```
private void _getCardapio(String result) {
    //...
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            //...

            // Agora voce possui um determinado array na posicao i
            JSONArray arrayDentroDoArray = json.getJSONArray(i);

            // Itera sobre cada objeto do array interno
            for(int j = 0; j < arrayDentroDoArray.length(); ++j) {
                JSONObject objeto = arrayDentroDoArray.getJSONObject(j);
                // Usar o objeto
            }

            //cardapioEntities.setCardapioPreco(convertCardapio(json.getJSONObject(i)).getCardapioPreco());
            //listaLanches.add(cardapioEntities);
        }
        //...
        final ListView lvLanches = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLanches);
        lvLanches.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listaLanches));
        //...
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Cuidado porque se o tipo da posição `i` não for um `Array` ele lançará uma `JSONException`. O que você poderia fazer, caso não tenha certeza, é:

```
Object o = json.get(i);

if(o instanceof JSONArray) {
    // Trabalhar com o Array
} else if(o instanceof JSONObject) {
    // Trabalhar com o objeto
}
```

Comment: Vou ter que fazer um outro `for` pro `arrayDentroDoArray`. Certo?

Comment: Isso, serão 2 iterações, uma para cada `JSONArray` e outra para cada `JSONObject` dentro de cada `JSONArray`.

Comment: Você não acha que vai criar um "`gargalo`" e deixar o app mais lento, ou não? rs

Comment: Você pode linearizar esse `JSON` inicial tendo apenas objetos e não listas de objetos. Eu acredito que não fica "lento", se você estiver usando `AsyncTask` ou `AsyncTaskLoader`. Se você estiver fazendo isso dentro da `MainThread` vai ficar lento sim... Se não estiver usando uma `AsyncTask` para decodificar esse `JSON`, recomendo que faça.

Comment: Como sugestão, deixo esses links: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html e http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html.

Comment: Perfeito; Sim, estou usando o `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Uma duvida: Pq ele fica repetindo o mesmo `Objeto` na ListView?

Comment: Como está seu código? Tem como postar na sua pergunta (O Adapter também se puder)? Os índices estão corretos?

Comment: Ok, Atualizado!

Answer (score 1):

acho q esses links irão ajuda-lo em sua dúvida!

http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-java-o-pacote-org-json/25480

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject

mais seria algo como:

```
 //string json: contém array com três elementos
    String json_str = "{\"elenco\":[\"Json Leigh\", \"Mary Stylesheet\",  \"David Markupovny\"]}";

    //instancia um novo JSONObject passando a string como entrada
    JSONObject my_obj = new JSONObject(json_str);

    //recupera o array "elenco"  
    JSONArray elenco = my_obj.getJSONArray("elenco");
```